# Why are Cases also listed under file storage?

Tags: data-storage, file-storage

I've been analysing our data and filse usage in an attempt to set up archiving mechanisms, and on the Storage Usage page **Cases are displayed both on the Data storage usage as in the File storage usage overviews.**

According to the [help](http://eu1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/admin_monitorresources.htm) they are definitely considered data and no special mention is made.

In the data storage overview:

```
Cases     1.086.918     2,1 GB  --> this is as expected
```

In the file storage overview:

```
Cases   1.086.918   118 KB
```

**does anyone know why this is listed**? (and ifso why this is so few KB) ?

**update:** I've mimicked a little poll below, I'm quite curious to know if this is also the case for others.

Comment: That's interesting. Because I'm working on a lot of different instances and I think I've never seen that before. According to the documentation, "File storage includes files in attachments, the Documents tab, the Files tab, the File field, Salesforce CRM Content, Chatter (including user photos), and Site.com assets."

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke did you ever find an answer to this one? It seems really weird.

Comment: Nope, nor am I sure it's still the case/org specific or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you use email2case, the likely culprit is all the logos in clients' email signatures.  Salesforce assumes those are useful attachments and keeps them associated with the case.

Comment: Would those not be stored and counted as attachements directly ? (and take up a lot more storage ?) The org has 2.5m emails and roughly the same amount of attachments.

Comment: I wouldn't swear to this, but I think they're treated differently.

Comment: Thankfully IC now has a new app that gets rid of those images - however it is really quite expensive for what it does https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B4CTZEA3